# Using Graphs Changes the Solutions for Diophantine Equation? Imperfection of Graph?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, graphing-functions

> Solve the Diophantine equation
>
> $$x^2+4y^2=z^2$$

The problem here is that I derived solutions using two different methods, and the both solutions do satisfy the given equation yet they are not the same! (1) and (2) is the way how I obtained solutions using different methods, and (3) deals with the core question I have. So if it's overwhelming somehow, then it would be glad if you could take a look at (3) at least.

**(1) Using Graph**

It is sufficient to find all rational solutions of equation

$$X^2 +4Y^2 =1:~X=\frac{x}{z}~\land~~Y=\frac{y}{z}$$

$Y=t(X+1)$ is a line which passes $(-1, 0)$ and another point $(m, n)$ with the slope $t$ on the equation above. By substituting the line equation to the equation above, we get

$$m=\frac{1-4t^2}{1+4t^2},~n=\frac{2t}{4t^2+1}$$

It is easy to show that $m, n \in \Bbb{Q}$ iff $t \in \Bbb{Q}$. Therefore, let $t=\frac{b}{a}$ where $(a, b)=1$. Then we get

$$m=\frac{a^2-4b^2}{a^2+4b^2},~n=\frac{2ab}{a^2+4b^2}$$

Therefore, let $(x, y, z)=(k(a^2-4b^2),~2kab,~k(a^2+4b^2))$. It is the solution for the very first Diophantine equation.

**(2) Not Using Graph**

It is easy to show that $x, z$ should have the same parity.

(i) When $z, x$ are odd, we have

$$4y^2=(z+x)(z-x)$$

Let $z+x=2u$ and $z-x=2v$. Since we are only interested in primitive solutions of the given equation, we can assume that $(z, x)=1$, then it is easy to show that $(u, v)=1$. Then we have

$$y^2=uv$$

Since $(u, v)=1$, let $u=a^2$ and $v=b^2$ where $(a, b)=1$. Then we have $y=ab,~x=a^2-b^2,~z=a^2+b^2$. Therefore, $(x, y, z)=(k(a^2-b^2),~kab,~k(a^2+b^2))$ is the solution for the very first Diophantine equation.

(ii) When $z, x$ are even, let $z=2z',~x=2x'$. Then we

$$x'^2+y^2=z'^2$$

Therefore, obviously $(x, y, z)=(4kab,~k(a^2-b^2),~2k(a^2+b^2))$ since $y$ should be odd in order to satisfy $(x, y, z)=1$.

**(3) Summary**

When we use graph, we get

$$(x, y, z)=(k(a^2-4b^2),~2kab,~k(a^2+4b^2))$$

If we don't use graph, we get

$$(x, y, z)=(k(a^2-b^2),~kab,~k(a^2+b^2)) ~\text{or}~ (4kab,~k(a^2-b^2),~2k(a^2+b^2))$$

This is really confusing. *First* thing is that anyway any of the solution does satisfy the Diophantine equation. *Second*, they are not the same. For example, in the soluton we obtained by graphical method $y$ should be always even. However, it is not required so in the latter solution. So I'm guessing the first solution is not denoting all the possible solutions of the equation. My question is... why? Since I did somewhat wrong or is it due to the imperfection residing in the graph itself? I don't get it...

*Third*, the answer in my book just says the all possible solutions are

$$(x, y, z)=(k(a^2-b^2),~kab,~k(a^2+b^2))$$

But it was the solution we obtained when $x, z$ were odd. Can we just replace it without adding another solution dervied when $x, z$ were even? Then why?

It is a long question, but I wanted to show every logic I used that has possibility of some flaws. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't read the entire thing, but here are some questions/thoughts you might investigate.  Did your assumptions in one of them effectively remove solutions?  Analogous to dividing by something that could very well be zero.  I see in the second method you restrict yourself to primitive solutions, but I see no mention of that in the first.  Related to that, is one of the solution sets a subset of the other?  If so, that strongly suggests that the smaller subset came from a method that removed solutions without you realizing it.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yes... Actually the conclusion we get from the first method is only the ratio of $x, y, z$ not the exact value. I was also guessing that was the answer for the second question. But what do you think about the third question?

Comment: More thoughts.  If you're only interested in primitive solutions, do you even need to consider the case where $z,x$ are both even?  If you do I don't see why your claim that you can force them co-prime in the odd case is justified.  I don't think you need the coprime assumption to progress, either.  Note that $z\pm x$ is even whenever $z,x$ have the same parity, so there's no need to distinguish the cases at that stage.  The "obviously" in the even case isn't really sticking out as obvious to me, incidentally.